# Dynamic Java Socket server Port

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ports

I am asked to build a server client chat application with dynamic ports Allocation ,my problem is that i can't retrieve the dynamic port from the client class , i tried several methods :Static members ,Singleton Design Patterns..but without success .Is there a method to do this ?
This is my server Constructor :

```
public Serveur() throws IOException{
    listen=new ServerSocket(0);
    port=listen.getLocalPort();
    System.out.println("Le serveur est demarre");
}
```

when i acces the variable port from the client class ,it returns the next free port ,which is incorrect ,please Help!!

Comment: What did you expect? What do you mean by "application with dynamic ports"? Server port **can not** be dynamic unless you broadcast the info somehow. Client port is **always** dynamic.

Comment: The posted code works without problems on my Sun Java 7 64 bit installation on (Win 7).

Comment: I think i wasnt clear enough ,my goal is is to NOT SPECIFY the port on which the server is on ,and establish the client connection to it

Answer (score 0):

> When I access the variable port from the client

Eh? You *can't* access the variable port from the client. You don't know what it is.

You have to work out a way for the server to tell the client what the port number is. You'll have to broadcast or multicast it from the server, or have the clients broadcast or multicast requests for it.

Or use a fixed port. It's much easier.